# Can't access date in ember-pikaday onSelection from the outside

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-components, pikaday

Has any of you experienced this using the ember-pikaday addon? I would like to set the date from the `onSelection` to be stored on the `selectedDate` but the context inside the onSelection is of the addon and not of the component itself. Is there a way I could store the value of `date` to one of the properties in my component?

My code is like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['schedule-nav-date-picker'],
  selectedDate: null,

  onSelection: function(date) {
    this.set('selectedDate', date);
    return date;
  },

  actions: {
    saveClicked () {
        this.sendAction('saveClicked', this.get('selectedDate'));
    },

    cancelClicked () {
      this.sendAction('cancelClicked');
    }

  }
});
```

And it gives me this error:

```
pikaday.js:165 Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...) is not a function
at Class.userSelectedDate (pikaday.js:165)
at Class.onPikadaySelect (pikaday.js:151)
at Backburner.run (ember.debug.js:224)
at Backburner.join (ember.debug.js:247)
at Function.run.join (ember.debug.js:15904)
at Pikaday.<anonymous> (ember.debug.js:15966)
at Pikaday.setDate (pikaday.js:815)
at HTMLDivElement.Pikaday.self._onMouseDown (pikaday.js:462)
```

And this is the template, (we use Emblem for templating):

```
h1 Select a Date
.form-groups-container.-include-container
  .form-section
    .form-group
      .row
        pikaday-inputless onSelection=onSelection

form-buttons [
  saveLabel='Save'
  cancelLabel='Cancel'
  saveClicked='saveClicked'
  cancelClicked='cancelClicked' ]
```

Comment: How do you include it in hbs?. From read me from addon , `{{pikaday-input onSelection=(action 'setSelectedDate')}}` and you can define `setSelectedDate` in your component.

Comment: Please update it in question that will be useful to others find problem

Comment: @kumkanillam yes, i already updated the question.

Comment: Try `pikaday-inputless onSelection=(action onSelection)`

Comment: It gives me the error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined` putting the `onSelection` under the `actions: {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main benefits of using `action` helper is that it automatically prepares `this` context for you; when you use it. For instance if you pass the function `onSelection` without the action helper like `{{pikaday-inputless onSelection=onSelection}}` then "this context" will be the `pikaday-inputless` component not your own component (parent component) within the handler function `onSelection`. This is what kumkanillam already mentioned in this comment. So you need to use `pikaday-inputless onSelection=(action 'onSelection')` for "this context" to be your own component.

I have prepared a very simple [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f58b07cc0968fe45f27636418e8cffcc?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) for you to illustrate that using action helper works smoothly. You just need to put your action handler within `actions` json declaration of your component. Check out `my-component` in the twiddle. It simply does what I already summarized above. Hope this helps.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to retain the selected date in the picker?

Comment: as far as I know; you cannot do that; `pikaday` relies on actions; you cannot directly bind to the selected date value; but again this is what I know; I might be wrong.